# Searching trough NLS message bundle classes without using reflection?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

I'm working on an application that has a huge list of key value pairs in multiple languages and I'm using the Eclipse RCP model with NLS.

For anyone unfamiliar with this, you have multiple properties files in different languages and the framework generates classes full of static strings for the current language.

Thus I can have `I18NMessageTooltip.Cancel` that provides a tooltip for the cancel button, in the currently selected language, whatever it may be. Same for labels and many other things.

The problem is, the same translation properties files have a great many things that I need to search trough.

As a stop gap, I made a search using reflection, but that is, in my opinion, quite inelegant.

Is there any other way to search through I18N static fields, other than either:

a. Reflection

b. Reinventing the wheel and searching through the properties files by hand

Comment: Search for what? It isn't clear from this what you are searching for.

Comment: @greg-449 I receive a string from a web service. That string is a key, I'm searching for the associated value. Both ar stored in i18n / properties files

Comment: The `NLS` class itself uses reflection to find the fields, I don't see any other way to do that.